# Ionic App throwing "Cannot read property 'id' of null at PinchRecognizer.recognizeWith" loading Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am working on an app written in TypeScript using the Ionic Framework. I'm attempting to load the first model into the forge viewer and I receive the below error when I attempt to call the viewer start method:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
    at PinchRecognizer.recognizeWith (viewer3D.js?v=4.0:2326)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at each (viewer3D.js?v=4.0:945)
    at invokeArrayArg (viewer3D.js?v=4.0:925)
    at PinchRecognizer.recognizeWith (viewer3D.js?v=4.0:2320)
    at new Autodesk.Viewing.GestureHandler (viewer3D.js?v=4.0:13760)
    at GuiViewer3D.Viewer3D.createControls (viewer3D.js?v=4.0:44610)
    at GuiViewer3D.Viewer3D.initialize (viewer3D.js?v=4.0:44694)
    at GuiViewer3D.initialize (viewer3D.js?v=4.0:50771)
    at GuiViewer3D.Viewer3D.start (viewer3D.js?v=4.0:44438)
    at PinchRecognizer.recognizeWith (viewer3D.js?v=4.0:2326)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at each (viewer3D.js?v=4.0:945)
    at invokeArrayArg (viewer3D.js?v=4.0:925)
    at PinchRecognizer.recognizeWith (viewer3D.js?v=4.0:2320)
    at new Autodesk.Viewing.GestureHandler (viewer3D.js?v=4.0:13760)
    at GuiViewer3D.Viewer3D.createControls (viewer3D.js?v=4.0:44610)
    at GuiViewer3D.Viewer3D.initialize (viewer3D.js?v=4.0:44694)
    at GuiViewer3D.initialize (viewer3D.js?v=4.0:50771)
    at GuiViewer3D.Viewer3D.start (viewer3D.js?v=4.0:44438)
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4620)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at o (polyfills.js:3)
    at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.js:3)
    at p (polyfills.js:2)
```

I read another stack overflow with the same issue, where there were competing libraries but I do not think that is the case for me. (Unless Ionic is utilizing something.)

Any ideas on what could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the feedback I received a while ago from a developer having the same exception than you on Cordova:

> I managed to find the cause of the console error. In hammer.js (which
>   is included in the viewer3D.js file), there is a method on the
>   ‘Manager’ object called ‘get(Recognizer)’ which contains a check
>   whether the provided parameter object is of type ‘Recognizer’. This
>   check somehow fails, causing the method to return null. This will
>   break the gesture handler later on in the call stack. I managed to fix
>   it in my environment by changing the check to check the object for
>   type ‘Object’ rather than ‘Recognizer’. This seems to fix my issue,
>   and does not seem to break other functionality. I couldn’t find
>   anything unusual on the Forge side that could have caused this issue
>   though, so it could be a generic problem.

Unfortunately I think you will have to use a custom modified version of the viewer3D.js source and patch the source yourself.

Comment: I was able to patch the source. This worked fairly well. My team is using version 4.0.1, which is not the version that the AutoDesk extractor is putting out (https://extract.autodesk.io/). So I am missing some extension files. Any ideas on how to get these? (Specifically, it is complaining about extensions/Measure/Measure.js, extensions/Section/Section.js, and extensions/Hyperlink/Hyperlink.js.)

Comment: You can just fetch them from the server: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/extensions/Measure/Measure.js?v=4.0.1. the EULA prevents us from making them available in an easier way (i.e. a direct public download of the whole SDK).

Comment: Thank you! I was able to grab what I needed!